# Can I mix Ktor with Exposed?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, nio, kotlin-exposed

I am writing a service using Ktor and Exposed ORM which apparently isn't async. I am coming from the Python world and back there using a blocking ORM with a async IO library is a sin as it may block all users in thread. 
Does the same rule apply in Kotlin? Am I creating a bad architecture?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be the same? As long as there is only 1 thread then the same will happen. You could though have a dedicated thread for Exposed. That way Ktor will work on a different, independent thread than Exposed and it won't be a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exposed uses thread local storage to keep transaction instance accessible to implementation and avoid passing it along with every function call. Since `transaction` DSL function is executing synchronously and do not release a thread to be reusable by ktor for other calls there shouldn't be any issues with using them together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am now confident and ready for production!

Comment: Surely blocking threads for DB work largely defeats the point of using an async framework?

Answer (score 6):

There is coroutine support in Exposed.

Please read the documentation:

https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Transactions#working-with-coroutines

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blogpost that shows how to use them together:

https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/04/14/kotlin-ktor-exposed-starter.html

I have also successfully done so myself in a test-project but I'm not yet at a point where I'm ready to share the code.

In short, you can use Kotlin coroutines in such a way that you do the database transaction on a thread so they do not block KTOR's request handling loop.
If using the right coroutine dispatcher, then this should not give any problem with the threadlocal transaction context.